# Как вписывать слева в Scale не только число, а еще и какое-то слово?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, scale

Как слева, рядом с числом, вписывать не только число, на котором находиться ползунок `scale`, а также какое-нибудь слово?

код:

```
def on_scroll(val):
    print(val)

scale = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=60, command=on_scroll, orient="horizontal")
scale.pack()
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scale.htm

Comment: @Эникейщик там не дан ответ на данный вопрос

Comment: Там дан ответ на этот вопрос. И на много других вопросов.

Comment: там лишь один пример со scale в котором выводиться просто число без всякого текста перед ним

Comment: Там ЦЕЛАЯ ТАБЛИЦА опций для scale. Остается только найти нужные и применить. Учись читать документацию, полезное умение.

Comment: там ничего не сказано про их применения

Comment: А что для каждой опции отдельный пример нужен? Все они применяются одинаково.

Comment: там ничего не сказано как можно к перед числом ползунка вставить слово, я перечитал внемательно всю документацию

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
scale = tk.Scale(root, variable=var, label='Hello')
```

Comment: в таком случае просто появляеться надпись Hello которая не двигаеться за ползунком

Comment: @Selasi неправильно понял вопрос. извиняюсь

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *


class Slider(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.slide = Scale(
            self, 
            length=400,
            sliderlength=20,
            showvalue=0,
            tickinterval=10,
            from_=0, 
            to=60, 
            command=self.setValue, 
            orient="horizontal"
        )
                           
        self.text = Label(self, font=('Arial',18))
        
        self.text.pack(anchor=CENTER)
        self.slide.pack() 


    def setValue(self, val):
        self.text.configure(text=f'Hello {val}')


root = Tk()
s = Slider(root)
s.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]